# Having trouble with showing database data in React Native app

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner in react native. In my app, I am fetching json encoded data from php backend. I fetched the data without a problem and tried in console. It worked perfectly.

Here's my code for fetching data.

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://bsthisarasinghe-001-site1.1tempurl.com/projectDetails.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            job_code: this.props.navigation.state.params.code
        })

    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({ data: responseJson.results });

        }).catch((error) => {

            Alert.alert("No internet connection");
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        });     
}
```

This is how I printed it in console.

```
onFocus1() {
    console.log(this.state.data[0].Job_Code);
}
```

But when I try to show the same string in app, it shows an error.

I tried this.

```
 <View style={{ width: '35%' }}>
     <Text style={styles.textBoldStyle}>Project Name: </Text>
 </View>
 <View style={{ width: '65%' }}>
     <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.state.data[0].Job_Code}</Text>
 </View>
```

Then it says

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Job_Code' of undefined"

What I want to create is this.

[image]

I want to add database data seperately to those places which typed as 'something'.
Please help me.

Comment: I think, you should check if the data is loaded or not before showing it like if this.state.data.length > 0 then ...

Comment: Data is loaded. I checked in console

Comment: i didn't say your data is not loaded. render of a component is called after every setState method. but before your data is loaded and called setState, your component is mounted with an empty data. So, you should control your data size in render method

Comment: Oh I understand.

Comment: I'll try to add a loading screen untill the data is loaded

Comment: I added a loading screen and till the data is loaded. It worked well. Thank you so much